# Dynamic Content Inside Cache Tag Helper - Donut Hole Caching

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I believe what I want to do used to be referred to as Donut Hole Caching.  I'm not sure how to implement it in .NET Core MVC though.  Essentially I have a large page, with static content by query string, except for a small part that needs to remain dynamic.  What I want can be summarized as:

```
<body>  
   <cache vary-by-query="...">
   @foreach(var item in Model)
   {
       <div class="lots-of-static-content"> 

           <cache enabled="false">
               <div class="dynamic-content>
               </div>
           </cache>

       </div>
   } 

   </cache>
</body>
```

I want to cache everything except the dynamic content.  Obviously, this isn't working - the dynamic content is still cached.  I'm sure this is a common problem, but I'm not sure what the correct way to approach it is, if anyone can offer some assistance.

Comment: Searching around it seems this feature (which was implemented in mvcdonutcaching) is still missing for asp.net core MVC.

Comment: I opened a thread in ASP.net forum, no luck at the moment. [see here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2147528.aspx?Donut+caching)

Answer (score -1):

You will find Donut caching with source code here.

https://github.com/moonpyk/mvcdonutcaching

You should find all the patterns and functionality you will need to achieve what you want. But you will need to translate them to .Net Core.